# Ruby how to call a class setter with yield

Tags: ruby, syntax, sinatra

I was able to get my code working, but I don't like the way it works syntaxually - not sure if that is even a word.

#### My code currently:

```
user.set_phone(phone) do
  message = "Verify your phone number #{@host}/phone/verify?id=#{user.id}&code=#{user.phone_verification_code}"
  CoreIntegrations::Sinch.send_text(message, phone)
end
```

#### How I would like it to look/work:

```
user.phone=(phone) do
  message = "Verify your phone number #{@host}/phone/verify?id=#{user.id}&code=#{user.phone_verification_code}"
  CoreIntegrations::Sinch.send_text(message, phone)
end
```

#### This is the Error I'm getting

```
/Users/christianjuth/Desktop/apollo-8/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:140: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do, expecting keyword_end /Users/christianjuth/Desktop/apollo-8/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:267: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

*The line number might in sync with the repo, case I have some local changes made to the application controller.*

...Or something along those lines. `user` is an ActiveRecord model. The reason I want to do this, is yield only gets called if the variable `phone` sent into `user.phone=` is different from the existing value of `user.phone`.

I think this is more of a syntax issue, but just in case [here is repo](https://github.com/space-hanger/apollo-8/tree/731ba44f5a13f5d8a3e0b13414af371ce3f4f817) for context. The code you are looking at lives in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`, and the user model can be found in `user/models/user.rb`.

#### UPDATE: I am having trouble calling the setter with yield not defining it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the method from `def set_phone` to `def phone=` then will be more difficult to invoke, but still possible:

```
user.send :phone=, phone do
  # ...
end
```

Comment: That wasn't the question. Sorry if I want clear. The reason I didn't include the definition is because I'm not asking how to define it, but how to call it.

Comment: @ChristianJuth you should be more specific in your question about what the problem is (i.e. an error). btw the word is "syntactically". Anyway see update to answer.

Comment: I edited the answer to try and fix any confusion. Sorry, I will be more careful in the future. Thanks for the help!